# Map displayed on R's widget doesn't get maximized when run through Qt

Tags: r, qt, ggplot2, ggmap, rinside

When I load a map on R's widget *(through `ggmap`)*  and run the program directly though R's console, the map gets properly maximized when I maximize the R's window.

The same doesn't happen when I run R through Qt. I am using RInside.
Through Qt when I run R, the widget gets shown indeed (with the map on it), but when I maximize the R window, the map does ***NOT*** get maximized. It remains the same sized!

It doesn't happen in any particular case. It happens all the time I run R though Qt, and never when I run R through R's console.

**What hardware/software information should be presented here?**

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
>
```

**Using Qt version 4.7.0**

```
> cat /etc/issue && uname -a
Welcome to openSUSE 11.4 "Celadon" - Kernel \r (\l).  
Linux linux-trra 2.6.37.1-1.2-desktop #1 SMP PREEMPT 2011-02-21 10:34:10 +0100 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**The simplest R program which causes this:**

```
R.parseEvalQ ("library (ggmap); library (raster);");

qtToR ["currentFileName"] = currentFileName;
R.parseEvalQ ("load (file = currentFileName); print (ggmap (mapImageData));");
```

[image]
Could it be possible that X11 server is not properly installed on my system? Or is this a know problem with `print`?

Is there any alternative way to get this running properly through ggmap?

![enter image description here][2]

Comment: please tell me if some other information is needed here.

Comment: Look at setting `window.options` (or `Xll.options`) and specifically `rescale`

Comment: @mnel I looked in `?x11.options` and saw this : `X11(display = "", width, height, pointsize, gamma, bg, canvas, fonts, family, xpos, ypos, title, type, antialias)` I couldn't find any option regarding resize/rescale.
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A temporary solution to the problem of map not getting maximized is to set the initial dimensions of `X11` server.

`X11 (width = 11, height = 11);`
This shows a nearly maximized window by default, and the map also gets shown maximized.